# Launch files: How to call rosaria and transforms

Tags: roslaunch, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I created a launch file to perform autonomous navigation with the robot. The launch file's contents can be seen below:

```
###launching rviz###
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" />

###start laser###
  <node pkg="sicktoolbox_wrapper" type="sicklms" name="sicklms" output="screen">
  <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyS1"/>
  <param name="inverted" value="true"/>
  </node>

###get map###
  <node pkg="map_server" type="map_server" name="map_server" args="/home/powerbot67/FacultyGNDFloorMapDan.yaml"/>
 
###RosAria###
  <node pkg="rosaria" type="RosAria" name="RosAria" output="screen" args="/home/powerbot67/catkin_ws/src" >
  <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyS0"/>
  <param name="DriftFactor" value="-20"/>
  <param name="TicksMM" value="115"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

To launch rosaria and transforms, I usually run the following commands succesfully in 2 separate terminals:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws
source ./devel/setup.bash
rosrun rosaria RosAria _port:=/dev/ttyS0 _DriftFactor:=-20 _TicksMM:=115

cd ~/transform_ws
source ./devel/setup.bash
rosrun transform transform
```

However, when I try to run rosaria using the launch file mentioned, I get the following error:

> ERROR: cannot launch node of type
> [rosaria/RosAria]: rosaria ROS path
> [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros ROS path
> [1]=/home/powerbot67/ros/eband_local_planner
> ROS path
> [2]=/home/powerbot67/ros/sbpl_lattice_planner
> ROS path
> [3]=/home/powerbot67/hydro/sandbox ROS
> path [4]=/opt/ros ROS path
> [5]=/opt/ros/hydro/share ROS path
> [6]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks

Any ideas as to why this is happening? How should I call transforms in this launch file? I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227649/launch-files:-how-to-call-rosaria-and-transforms/) by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2016-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, it looks like roslaunch is unable to find the RosAria node in its ROS search path.  Did you source `devel/setup.bash` before running roslaunch?  (Same as you do before using rosrun)

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2016-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on 2016-03-07**:
Thanks for your reply. What should I add to the launch file in order to source devel/setup.bash ?

**Comment by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on 2016-03-23**:
Just in case, someone has the same problem: Adding the launch file to the catkin_ws folder and then typing the following commands solves the issue:

cd ~/catkin_ws
source ./devel/setup.bash
roslaunch Navigation.launch

Thanks all

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-06-20**:
@DanThe That's not the best way to go about it. It's pretty common to source the workspace from your `~/.bashrc` file then use `roslaunch` to launch it from the package. If you do things differently from the "ROS way" then you start making it harder to share your work and for others to use it.